# Check whether the following are eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matri

Tags: linear-algebra

"Check whether the following are eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix. Justify your answer. If the answer is yes, give the matrix."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehdmC.png

I know how to calculate the matrix with the given eigenvalues and eigenvectors but I don't know how to check if they are eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix without having/knowing the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

- The eigenvectors of a matrix corresponding to *distinct* eigenvalues must be linearly independent.
- If $\ v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\ $ are linearly independent eigenvectors of an $\ n\times n\ $ matrix, $\ M\ $, corresponding to eigenvalues $\ \lambda_1,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\ $ (not necessarily distinct), and $\ V\ $ is the matrix with columns $\ v_1,$$ v_2,$$ \dots,$$ v_n\ $, then
  $$
     MV=V\text{diag}\big(\lambda_1,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\big)\ ,
   $$
  and so
  $$
  M=V\text{diag}\big(\lambda_1,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\big)V^{-1}\ .
  $$